# I cant access the files I upload with django inside the website with nginx when I try to download them

Tags: python, django, nginx

In my python Django project I can't figure out how to download .pdf files with nginx.

In the site there will be constant uploads from an admin an the site shows the download links for this button in html and I direct to download with href.

I tried to define a dynamic location in nginx locations but it just gives me a "404 not found" or " the requested resource was not found on this server.". I checked that files exists at the correct path but nginx still does not work.

Nginx Location File :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 134.209.252.222;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/mjr/hedefcekilis/mysite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    location /static/admin {
   root /home/mjr/hedefcekilis/cekilisenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin;
}

    location ~ \.(pdf) {
        root /home/mjr/hedefcekilis/mysite/media/ibra/~;
    }
}
```

The pdf files are in different folders in the "ibra" folder. And these folder names change over time. How can I solve this problem?

Edit:

Example path to a file :

```
~/project/mysite/media/ibra/evyapwatson_HJvsTBf./Page-1.pdf
```

Static:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static2/')
```

Comment: Pls provide a complete example. What is the absolute path to the file in the file system, what is the exact URI that you request, what are your STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL settings? Also check the permissions of the file, if your nginx is run by a different user than your gunicorn, it might not have sufficient permissions to read that file.